# Can't find fuse for radio

Tags: electronics

Honda Accord 2012 has 3 fuse panels and no fuses labeled radio.  I have checked several labeled accessories and can't find blown fuse.  Can you icentify correct fuse for radio?

Comment: Have you consulted the owner's manual before coming here?

Comment: Might be labelled "ACC" - I *think* it's #9 in the passenger side fusebox but won't swear to that! If your car has the "Premium" sound system there should be a separate fuse for the amp somewhere as well.

Comment: There should be a fuse section in the owners manual that will tell what the fuses are.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this link, I would suggest looking at 17 and 18 in the driver side fuse box.

https://www.autogenius.info/honda-accord-2011-2012-fuse-box-diagram/

Answer (score 0):

Friend, your owners manual will tell you.